# Regarding joins and subquery

Tags: sql, db2

I have below query that I am using ..

```
select  * from app_subsys_param where assp_name like '%param_name%'
```

where param_name is the name of the parameter. From this query we will get the assp_id corresponding to the parameter. With this id we look up into app_subsys_parmval table to get the value of the parameter.

```
 update app_subsys_parmval  set aspv_value = 'true' where assp_id = id_val
```

Now instead of separately launching the two sql statements , I want to combime both of them as one is there any sub query or join mechanism that can combine both of them in one statement , please advise

Comment: Please let us know what RDBMS you are using so we can supply the right syntax.

Comment: For db2, go with Flimzy's answer. That woudld be the appropriate syntax. I'll remove mine

Comment: You're using a string with `'true'` in it?  If you're on a version that doesn't support a logical type (LUW, say), I think I'd rather go with a 1/0 combination (or character '1'/'0').  Or, probably better yet, make a user-defined type.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `UPDATE .. FROM` syntax:

```
UPDATE app_subsys_paramval
SET aspv_value = 'true'
FROM app_subsys_param
WHERE app_subsys_param.id = app_subsys_paramval.id
    AND app_subsys_param.value LIKE '%param_name%';
```

Comment: It's db2, so this is the way to go. +1

Comment: @Michael Thnanks a lot dude..!

Comment: DB2 on Linux/UNIX/Windows does not support `UPDATE … FROM` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subselect in your update statement:

```
UPDATE app_subsys_parmval  
SET aspv_value = 'true' 
WHERE id_val = (SELECT assp_id 
                FROM app_subsys_param 
                WHERE assp_name LIKE '%param_name%')
```

Note, I am assuming a bit about what's in the `*` of your `select *`.

Comment: @lc..could you please update the post soo that I can have  look that will make understanding more clear, thanks

Comment: why the downvotes? This post is constructive and answering the question. Nowadays, if you don't also cut the meat in people's plates they downvote...

Comment: @Sebas Because the original answer was a useless placeholder that only said _Use a subselect in your update statement_. It was only edited to include content after the downvotes.

Comment: this is still the answer in my current page, and I don't see the problem of answering that way... Downvote is intended to be used for non constructive and useless answers. This shouldn't be applied here.

Comment: @Michael While the original answer was short, it could have prompted the OP to use the keyword "subselect" in a Google search to learn more about the topic. A lot of times people come here first because they don't know what to look for, so I humbly disagree with your use of the word "useless".

Comment: Downvote = "This answer is not useful."  "Use a subselect in your update statement" is *barely* useful, at best.  It's also not a good approach to the problem, but that's a technical issue.

Comment: @Flimzy As you can see, I have updated my answer to include an example. Besides, your suggestion is to use `UPDATE FROM` which is not supported in all RDBMS and non-standard. Please do enlighten me on how this is not a good approach to the problem. Well, now we know it's db2, that makes `UPDATE FROM` valid. But, just as I updated my answer, the OP has updated their question...

Comment: @lc.: I would remove my downvote now, but your edit happened too quickly. The system thinks your edit was part of your original post... my dv is locked in :/ (I made an edit myself so I could remove my DV)

Comment: @Flimzy Fair enough and thank you. I would still like to learn why this is not a good approach to the problem though.

Comment: @lc.: Because it doesn't allow the query planner to optimize the join. (Although some implementations may be clever enough to turn a simple subselect like that into a join)

Comment: @Flimzy Interesting. I was under the impression that most implementations *were* clever enough. I'll have to keep my eyes open.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `MERGE` statement.  This is the ANSI SQL:2003 standard for `UPDATE … FROM`.

Documentation:

- [MERGE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html) for DB2 for Linux/UNIX/Windows
- [MERGE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_merge.htm) for DB2 z/OS 9.1